# How to aggregate array keys in Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

Is it possible to aggregate the keys of fields of Elastic documents? I read through the [Elastic aggregation documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations.html) and tried some coding, but didn't succeed.

Existing documents:

```
{ 
    "analysis": {         
      "v1": {"a":1, "b":2}
    }
}          


{ 
    "analysis": {         
      "v1": {"a":3, "b":4}
    }
}          


{ 
    "analysis": {         
      "v2": {"a":5, "b":6}
    }
}          


{ 
    "analysis": {         
      "v1": {"a":7, "b":8},
      "v2": {"a":9, "b":10},
    }
}
```

Expected outcome of the aggregation is the count of keys:

```
{
    "v1": 3,
    "v2": 2
}
```

*Updated source JSON*

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the field having that data?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean to aggregate on a non-leaf node?

Comment: Currently there is no dedicated mapping, documents are just inserted individually and everything else is Elastic magic. Should I do a mapping? And yes, I want to aggregate the (key) names of the non-leaf nodes. I updated the source JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GET /your_index_name/your_type_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "v1": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "analysis.v1"
        }
      }
    },
    "v2": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "analysis.v2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I have to manually include every existing version of the analysis. Not perfect, as we have a lot of versions (e.g. v2_3_4), but it's a good start.